# how to get two column values in a single query using linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a `member` table with columns

```
 memberid
 Firstname( values like john,pop...)
 secondname(values like ..david ,rambo..)
```

i want to get the firstname and secondname in a single query

i want something like this..

```
john david
pop rambo
```

i know how to do in mysql like this..

```
  string sql = select (Firstname,'',secondname) as fullname from members...
```

but i dont know how to get the full name  using linq to entities ...

my entity name is `dbcontext`

would any one help on this..

Many thanks In advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from m in member
select new {
             FULLNAME = String.Concat(m.Firstname+" ", m.secondname)       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use C# string manipulation:

```
List<string> names =  from m in ctx.members
    select m.firstname + ' ' + m.secondname;
```

Or use a more elaborate function to handle missing names etc.